# how to optimize update query in pymongo for scraping project

Tags: mongodb, web-scraping, indexing, pymongo, insert-update

how to create and refresh index in pymongo to speed up update queries.
As mentioned in the article[1] section, the following is code works fine for small set of entries

```
    self.collection.update({'url': item['url']}, dict(item), upsert=True)
```

But once it reaches in tens of thousands, it is very slow.

[1] https://realpython.com/web-scraping-and-crawling-with-scrapy-and-mongodb/#mongodb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an index on `url` field

https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.create_index

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/

```
self.collection.create_index('url')
```

---

In your case `url` will be unique, you can create a unique index.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/#unique-indexes

```
self.collection.create_index('url', unique = True)
```

Note- If you've huge existing data create the index in the background

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-creation/